# browserAction.getTitle() not working in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

The following code is failing :

```
var currentIcon = chrome.browserAction.getTitle(function(result){
                                                            return result;
        });

alert(currentIcon);
```

Please help resolving the problem.Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct code is :

```
chrome.browserAction.getTitle({},function(result){
                                                alert(result);
                          });
```

Comment: For anyone else looking at this code and wondering why, it is because the call to getTitle is asynchronous.

Answer (score 2):

`chrome.browserAction.getTitle` is an asynchronous function.

Use the following:

```
chrome.browserAction.getTitle(details, function(result){
    alert(result);
});
```